# Changing background colour of ion-navbar using *ngIf

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Using ion-navbar and Firebase Database.

What I would like to see is that according to the "color" child in the Firebase DB, a different ion-navbar background colour would be shown.

I'm currently using *ngIf to work out my problem, but I can't get it to function. It keeps showing me a blue background (#85dec8, the last *ngIf statement) regardless of the color of this.selectedItem.color.

My code:

```html
   <ion-navbar class="bar">
    <ion-title class="bar">{{selectedItem.name}}</ion-title>
    <style *ngIf="selectedItem.color=='#ffce4e'">
      .bar {
        background-color: #ffce4e;
      }
    </style>
    <style *ngIf="selectedItem.color=='#f55f7c'">
        .bar {
          background-color: #f55f7c;
        }
    </style>
    <style *ngIf="selectedItem.color=='#85dec8'">
        .bar {
          background-color: #85dec8;
        }
    </style>
  </ion-navbar>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`[style.background-color]`](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/)

```
   <ion-navbar class="bar">
         <ion-title class="bar" [style.background-color]="selectedItem.color">{{selectedItem.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

See example here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z2pb8w?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

**Or you can use [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) then you will have to use css**

```
   <ion-navbar class="bar">
         <ion-title class="bar" [ngClass]="{'bar': selectedItem.color=='#ffce4e', 'barA': selectedItem.color=='#f55f7c', 'barB':selectedItem.color=='#85dec8'}">{{selectedItem.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
```

*In css:*

```
  .bar {
    background-color: #ffce4e;
  }
.barA {
  background-color: #f55f7c;
}

.barB {
  background-color: #85dec8;
}
```

Here is example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3kgulw?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Hmm, I copied your code exactly, but it is only showing me a background colour for the "84dec8" (blue) colour. For example, the #ffce4e selectedItem does not even have a background colour.

Comment: Also, it looks like [ngStyle.color] isn't a known usable property of ion-title or ion-navbar

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working. Perhaps it's an error on Ionic's part?

Comment: It is quite an odd thing, but again it is only showing css changes for the last class (.barB .toolbar-title). It's really frustrating.

Comment: or https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-z2pb8w?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
you should use `ngClass` here.

```
  <style>
  .bar1 {
    background-color: #ffce4e;
  }
  .bar2 {
      background-color: #f55f7c;
  }
  .bar3 {
      background-color: #85dec8;
  }
 </style>
 <ion-navbar [ngClass]="{'bar1' : selectedItem.color=='#ffce4e', 'bar2' : 
 selectedItem.color=='#f55f7c', 'bar3' : selectedItem.color=='#85dec8'}">
 <ion-title class="bar">{{selectedItem.name}}</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>`
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but your method does not work. I used your method exactly and it didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @caroline apparently I missed the trailing `}` I've edited it and you need to add the same condition on the `<ion-title>` tag as well.

Comment: Hi @Jazib, I've done what you've suggested, but again it is not working. Terribly unfortunate..